# Mostrar u Ocultar contenido con un checkbox (Vue)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

lo que estoy intentando hacer es que SI se marca un `checkbox`, se muestren algunas etiquetas dentro de un `<template>`, y si se desmarca este mismo `checkbox`, Se vuelvan a ocultar.

Y básicamente este es el código que estoy utilizando, he probado varias combinaciones pero no encuentro la forma de que funcione.

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="toggle" true-value="yes" false-value="no"/>
  
                    <label>Mostrar | Ocultar</label>

                 <template v-if= vm.toggle>

                     <p>Mostrado </p>
                     <p>Mostrado </p>

                 </template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que buscas hacer es más fácil de lo que crees.

Como ya tienes la variable `toggle` en el `v-model` del checkbox, entonces solo tienes que inicializar dicha variable dentro del `data` del componente.

```
var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#vm',
      data: function () {
        return {
          toggle: false
        }
      }     
 })
```

Luego, en el `v-if` del `template` no necesitas llamarla como `vm.toggle`, si no simplemente como `toggle`.

Con todo esto, no veo necesarios los atributos `true-value="yes"` y `false-value="no"` que le pones al checkbox.

Ejecuta el código completo, y verifica si hace lo que esperabas:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vm',
  data: function () {
    return {
      toggle: false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.6/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vm">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="toggle" />
  
  <label>Mostrar | Ocultar</label>

  <template v-if="toggle">
    <p>Mostrado </p>
    <p>Mostrado </p>
  </template>
</div>
```